# How can I limit query's results without using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, limit

I need to show ordered 20 records on my grid but I can't use LIMIT because of my generator(Scriptcase) using LIMIT to show lines per page. It's generator's bug but I need to solve it for my project. So is it possible to show 20 ordered record from my table with a query?

Comment: Is user defined variables are allowed by your generator(Scriptcase)  ?

Answer (score 1):

As from comments,if you can't use limit then you can rank your results on basis of some order and in parent select filter limit the results by rank number

```
select * from (
select *
,@r:=@r + 1 as row_num
from your_table_name
cross join (select @r:=0)t
order by some_column asc /*  or desc*/
) t1 
where row_num <= 20
```

[`Demo with rank no.`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce840/2)

Another hackish way would be using `group_concat()` with order by to get the list of ids ordered on asc/desc and   `substring_index` to pick the desired ids like you need 20 records then join with same table using `find_in_set` ,But this solution will be very expensive in terms of performance and group_concat limitations if you need more than 20 records

```
select t.* 
from your_table_name t
join (
select 
substring_index(group_concat(id order by some_column asc),',',20) ids_list
from your_table_name
  ) t1 on (find_in_set(t.id , t1.ids_list) > 0)
```

[`Demo without rank`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce840/5)

Comment: You can do this without a subquery just use having instead of where

Comment: @JohnRuddell No,because having comes before order by and in rank query case order is important also if i do as you suggests it will be wrong because having clause evaluates the whole expression again and it will assign wrong rank no. to records i have created a small demo for 2 records [*Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d289a2/3) but see it returns only one ,[*another demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d289a2/4) to get 3 records it returns 2 with wrong ranks hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Ok if the order is important then yes you should do a subquery.. But from personal experience the variable should be in the outer query because the evaluation is sometimes triggered before ordering.. If you order and get your result then add variables itll work everytime

Comment: Like this here [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01cbc/4) +1 regardless though this is how I'd do it :)

Answer (score 0):

What about SELECT in SELECT:

```
SELECT *
   FROM (
       -- there put your query
       -- with LIMIT 20
   ) q
```

So outer SELECT is without LIMIT and your generator can add own.

Answer (score 0):

In a Scriptcase Grid, you CAN use Limit. This is a valid SQL query that selects only the first 20 records from a table. The grid is set to show only 10 records per page, so it will show 20 results split in a total of 2 pages:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID,
    ProductName
FROM 
    Products
LIMIT 20
```

Also the embraced query works out well:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID,
    ProductName
 FROM 
    (SELECT 
    ProductID,
    ProductName
  FROM Products  LIMIT 20) tmp
```